# Determine the PID of a process that is calling out to an IP

Tags: network-interface, wireshark

My wifi card is tryign to make a connection to a seemingly random IP address on the local network.  I want to find which process on the client is trying to make this connection to determine why.

This situation is particularly MacOS, but I'm also curious about how to do this in other Linux/Unix variants.  The mac is connected to the local network via Wifi.  I have re-installed MacOS High Sierra from USB on a wiped drive and the wifi card still tries to make this connection.

Packet capture of network traffic with Wireshark shows that the network card is calling out roughly every 1 minute 30 seconds, attempting to make a connection to an IP on the local network (192.168.86.173, Port 7000) by sending a SYN packet.  Then several re-transmissions of the SYN take place, since there is no response from the IP the client is trying to reach.

[image: Wireshark capture of attempted connection from client to unknown LAN host]

I have `ping` and `nmap` the IP 192.168.86.173, but no response.  I have used network scanner and no device shows on that IP.

I looked up port 7000 and only found a file-server that uses UDP, not TCP. (https://www.auditmypc.com/tcp-port-7000.asp), and something called Gryphon for automobile testing that uses TCP (http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/ip/ports07000.htm).

I have tried close all applications on the desktop and then using `lsof -i tcp`. From the man page:

> -i [i]   selects the listing of files any of whose Internet address
> matches the address specified in i.  If no address is
> specified, this option selects the listing of all Internet
> and x.25 (HP-UX) network files.

The process is not listed, even when running this process while the SYN and re transmission SYN packets are being sent no process shows up.  Is there a way to determine which process on my client is trying to establish this connection?

Is there a `netstat` commmand that will only show attempted outgoing connections I can run in a loop that will return a `PID` and command name?

I guess I cannot get a `PID` or command name from `Wireshark` since its too low level?

Comment: Linux: `nethogs` but only for TCP connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the syn packet is part of an actual connection attempt you could, at just the right moment list the socket and the process with something like:

```
netstat -apn | grep SYN_SENT
```

This works on Linux. The `-p` flag lists the name of the process that owns the socket. You can refine/change the `grep` condition to get just the line you're after.

For MacOs you can do:

```
lsof -i -P | grep -i "SYN_SENT"
```

Going back to Linux, an alternative is to set up a server at that address/port by redirecting it to a local process:

```
# iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 7000 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:7777

$ nc -l 7777
```

Now, since the connection will be established, you will have more time to run the `netstat -p...` command before the socket is closed.

```
netstat -apn | grep 7000
```

And you might also be able to trigger the flow of some tcp data on that connection, that could allow you to know more about the client.

In Linux you'd use `ss`, but you mentioned MacOS, and it has `netstat` for sure. Note that you might have to run `netstat` and `lsof` as root to be able to list all sockets.

Comment: Since as I mentioned this is on `MacOs`, and `IPTables` isn't available I continued with the `netstat` command. I will look for a mac equivalent of `IPtables`.  However, `netstat -an -p tcp | grep SYN_SENT` did return something when I ran it at exactly the correct moment:  `tcp4       0      0  192.168.5.11.51948     192.168.86.173.7000    SYN_SENT`. However, that did not return a process ID.

Comment: I updated the answer for MacOs. I cannot test it, it should work with `lsof`.

Comment: I altered the command to `netstat -anvt | grep SYN_SENT` for MacOs.  the `-v` is for verbose output.  I got a process id and found out that it was MacOs `AirPlayXPCHelper`.